# How to display value of value of another variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = "bar"
var bar  = "realvalue";
```

Is it possible to print the value of `bar` using `foo` ?

Comment: I'm quite curious what the use case for this is? When would you use it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Approach 1: global variable

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar  = "realvalue";
alert(window[foo]);
```

OR

Approach 2: namespace
Divide your js to namespaces

```
var namespace = {
 foo : "bar",
 bar : "realvalue"
};
alert(namespace[namespace.foo]);
```

Comment: I like this solution. The namespace thing, though not really a namespace but a javascript object, is really cool.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Isn't the first solution limited to a browser? will it work in a node.js app?

Answer (score 17):

Yeah you can do something like this with `eval`

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar  = "realvalue";
alert(eval(foo));
```

EDIT: Seems a lot of people are against using the eval() function. My advice before using it is read this question: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Then once you understand the risks you can decide for yourself if you wish to use it.

Comment: It shows how to use eval in this case, whether `eval` is evil is another thing, its a correct and valid answer

Comment: Though I don't agree with the `eval` command, this solution still has it's importance because it's good to know. In some cases you can't go without it...

Comment: -1 I consider this to be a bad answer, because it suggests using dangerous functionalities where safer alternatives exist. If it suggested to avoid eval, or potential problems with using eval, or that those problems even exist, or better alternatives, I would remove my down-vote.

Comment: @ANeves Added a disclaimer in the answer :)

Comment: @cowls now I only disagree with the suggestion, and don't think it is misleading any more. Down-vote removed. :)

Answer (score 14):

If it's a global variable you can use `window[foo]`

Comment: No it is not global variable. But I didn't knew we can use window[foo] for global variable, so +1 . Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Don't do this kind of constructs with non-global variables, just scope whatever variables you would otherwise have floating around.

```
var myscope = {
    bar: 'realvalue'
},
foo = 'bar';

alert(myscope[foo]);
```

Btw, the above doesn't rely on the default behaviour of browsers to also register global variables in the `window` object, making it work for things like Node.js too.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are defined on the `window` object, so you can use:

```
var bar = "realvalue";
alert(window["bar"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar  = "realvalue";
foo=bar;
console.log(foo);
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var foo = "bar";
 var bar  = "realvalue";
 alert(eval(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via `eval`. But unfortunately, not without `eval`, which is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to use.

Comment: Still, Please tell me the `eval` solution.

Comment: I got it alert ( eval ( foo ) ); And that's what I needed.

Comment: eval is evil; Nice! Just like Uranium is evil.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal Not really like Uranium. Uranium has way more and better uses than `eval()`.